# Sending HTML input value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I don't know what's wrong with my code, it didn't work.

My controller :

```
public function add_user_driver()
{
    if(!$this->user_permission->check_permission())return;
        $plate_number               =   $this->input->post('plate_number');
        $location_id                =   $this->input->post('location_id');

        $data_user = array(
            'plate_number'              => $plate_number,
            'location_id'               => $location_id,
            );

        $this->db->insert('user_driver', $data_user);         
    echo json_encode(array("plate_number" => $plate_number, "location_id" => $location_id));

}
```

The view :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="usermodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">USER_DRIVER</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id='add'>
            <div class="row" id="form_pesan">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="plate_number"  name="plate_number"  placeholder="Plate Number" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="location_id" name="location_id" placeholder="Location Id" required>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick=add()>Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form_submit_result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    matchFormFields = "#form_pesan input[required]";

    matchFormSubmitResult = "#form_submit_result";

    errorColor = 'red';
});

function add(){
    var formIsValid = true;
    $(matchFormFields).each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', '');
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())) {
            $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);
            formIsValid = false;
        }
    });
    if (formIsValid) {
        plate_number = $("#plate_number").val(); 
        location_id = $("#location_id").val(); 
        $.ajax
        ({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('admin/add_user_driver')?>/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data:{plate_number: plate_number, location_id: location_id},
            success: function(data)
            {     
                $("#usermodal").modal("hide");
                $("#alert").show();
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                notify('Error data');
            }

        });
    };
}
```

I want to submit value from input text to JavaScript `add` function, but somehow, the `.val()` doesn't return the actual value. What did I do wrong?

Comment: add `<form>` element inside the model. And adding `{}` in your code(in controller if function) will not charge for additional cost of spacing..

Comment: did you check console?

Comment: `matchFormFields` this variable is defined? try after changing this `data:{plate_number: plate_number, location_id: location_id},` to `data:{plate_number: $("#plate_number").val(), location_id: $("#location_id").val()},`

Comment: @user6838959 that will not be an issue. Check above on ajax code

Comment: @may what happen when you click sumbit button ?? did you print alert on it ??

Comment: it should be insert new record to database, but it's not :( @Spartan

Comment: i try `console.log` it showing the value ! but not inserting to database @NikhilVaghla

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` add this and check controller

Comment: look at my edited question, it is defined before the `add` function. i just not provided at the previous question

Comment: please mark that when iterating over `$(matchFormFields)` you will also have the `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />` to take into consideration. Does that have any value?

Comment: var plate_number = $("#plate_number").val(); 
var location_id = $("#location_id").val();

did you try declaring the variable using 'var'? try to alert the variables and see...

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: did you try to console $("#plate_number").val() ? does it have value?

Comment: yes, it has value, but it's not inserting to database. maybe there's something wrong with my controller, i just can't find it yet @NewbeeDev

Comment: did you try to var_dump($this->input->post()); does it have result?

Comment: yey check your database maybe there's some column which are not allowed null that you have leave

Comment: @NewbeeDev it gives me `notify is not defined` suddenly, it works fine yesterday :(

Comment: did you do some changes into your db yesterday?

Comment: no, i have not made any changes :( @NewbeeDev

Comment: try getting the latest query executed in codeigniter then copy paste it to your phpmyadmin

Comment: @NewbeeDev thanks, it's because there are columns not allowed null. silly of me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
datatype: "json"
```

or

```
datatype: "text"
JSON.stringify({plate_number: plate_number, location_id: location_id})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = $("#plate_number").val();
alert(abc);
return false;
```

You can use the variable `abc` in javascript.